# How can I store the value of each iteration of a FOR loop into a vector in R?

Tags: r, arrays, loops, for-loop, vector

I need to store the variable "result" into a vector. I have been trying for days. Still can't get through it

```
for(i in 1:10)
{
  avgcol<-c(q[i])
  numofNA<-sum(is.na(clnvar[i,]))
  monthsnoNA<-31-numofNA
  result=avgcol/monthsnoNA
  
newvar<-c(result,i)

  
  
}
```

I Would like to have a vector with all the values gotten from the iterations of the for loop. The solution I tried won't work. It does not create a vector. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the `result` outside and then assign based on the index

```
result <- numeric(10)
for(i in 1:10)
 {
   avgcol <-c(q[i])
  numofNA <- sum(is.na(clnvar[i,]))
  monthsnoNA<-31-numofNA
  result[i] <- avgcol/monthsnoNA
}
```